# Python Global Variable Error

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a Gross Wage calculator program in Python and I believe I am hitting a Global Variable error:

NameError: global name 'WorkedTimed' is not defined

My code is below. I believe I defined WorkedTime through the raw_input command, but for some reason it is returning as not defined. Any help is appreciated. I am within my first two months of coding. Thanks!

```
def GrossWage():
    WorkedTime = raw_input('Please enter hours worked for previous week.\n')
    PayRate = raw_input('Please enter pay rate for previous week.\n')  
    OverTime = WorkedTime - 40
    StandardTime = 40

    if WorkedTimed > 40:
        print ((StandardTime * PayRate) + (Overtime (PayRate + Payrate * .5)))
    else:
        print WorkedTime * PayRate

GrossWage()
```

Comment: `WorkedTime` is not `WorkedTimed`.

Comment: If you check properly , you have defined "WorkedTime" and you are trying to compare using "WorkedTimed".

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, dumb mistake. I receive an operand error for Overtime = WorkedTime - 40 ... I thought if I input an integer as WorkedTime, it stores as an integer. But my next error is telling me: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues besides the one in your question. So to answer your question (as TigerhawkT3 commented) you have defined `WorkedTime` but used `WorkedTimed`. Simple typo which is going to always challenge to find, but learn to look for that cause first as it will save a lot of headaches.

Next one is your trying to use a string and a integer in maths. I tend to define upfront when I set the variable casting it to the right type, in this case something like changing your first WorkedTime line to `WorkedTime = float(raw_input('Please enter hours worked for previous week.\n'))`.

You will see doing similar will fix a few other problems you are about to find.

You may also find a problem with the formula for greater than 40 hours (it's another typo where your missing an operator)